# Delete Loop in MS Access using SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I have the following data generated by a SQL select query. The data is sorted ascending first by ID and then descending by AVO, as shown below:

```
+-------+----------------+------+-------+---------+----------+-----+
|  ID   |      Link      | Name | Type  | Subtype | Domicile | AVO |
+-------+----------------+------+-------+---------+----------+-----+
| 11111 | www.aaaaa3.com | AAAA | FUND  | 40 act  | USA      | 456 |
| 11111 | www.aaaaa2.com | AAAA | FUND  | 40 act  | USA      | 456 |
| 11111 | www.aaaaa6.com | AAAA | FUND  | 40 act  | UK       | 345 |
| 11111 | www.aaaaa1.com | AAAA | FUND  | 40 act  | USA      | 123 |
| 11111 | www.aaaaa4.com | AAAA | FUND  | 40 act  | USA      |     |
| 11111 | www.aaaaa5.com | AAAA | FUND  | 40 act  | USA      |     |
| 22222 | www.bbbb1.com  | BBBB | BANK  | Inv     | Canada   | 897 |
| 22222 | www.bbbb5.com  | BBBB | BANK  | Inv     | Brazil   | 586 |
| 22222 | www.bbbb3.com  | BBBB | BANK  | Inv     | Cayman   | 357 |
| 22222 | www.bbbb2com   | BBBB | BANK  | Inv     | Cayman   |     |
| 22222 | www.bbbb4.com  | BBBB | BANK  | Inv     | Cayman   |     |
+-------+----------------+------+-------+---------+----------+-----+
```

What I need to do is to keep only one row per ID with the largest value in the field AVO for each ID and delete the others. If two identical values in the AVO field exist for any given ID (see first two rows in table above), then keep the first row and delete the other.

I think I could do it in VBA with a For...Next loop for every ID value but I'd rather run this in SQL. Is this even possible? Is it possible to nest a loop in a SQL Delete query in Access?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You need to be specific about which one you want to keep if you want to use SQL. The first two records you shared have an equal ID and AVO, so with your current criteria, I don't know which one should be kept.

Comment: Either actually, this is why I referred to "keep the first row", as in first location wise. I can't generate a criteria per se because in principle it is possible for two rows to be absolutely identical except for the link field. If I didn't have that field I could filter out these instances with the DISTINCT command but that won't work in this specific example.

Comment: In SQL, you can't just say "either", you need to specify. If rows are identical, add an autonumber to keep them from being identical.

Comment: I can add an autonumber to the table. But then how do I tell Access that for each ID, it should delete all rows except the one with the highest value in the AVO field? How is adding the autonumber help me sort the delete issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've added an AutoNumber field named `AN`, you can use the following query:

```
DELETE * FROM MyTable
WHERE AN NOT IN(
    SELECT AN From (MyTable t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(AN) AS MaxAN, ID, AVO  FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID, AVO) t2 ON t1.AN = t2.MaxAN)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, Max(AVO) As MaxAVO FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID) t3 ON (t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.AVO = t3.MaxAVO)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful as I'm self taught and this was a bit outside my domain. I will build it and test it out the next hour or so. I will revert shortly. In the meantime, my sincere thanks to you.

Comment: I'm sorry but your notation T1 and T2 doesn't make sense to me. Are you using those to rename temp tables? The query doesn't seem to create any so I'm very puzzled.

Comment: Those are aliases. If you run this against the sample data you shared (only change is there's an autonumber field named AN) it should just work

Comment: I did but it doesn't cause I'm running it in Access not in the SQL server. Aliases for what?

Comment: This is an Access query. It should work in Access, and I've verified it. Aliases for subqueries. For example, `(SELECT Max(AN) AS MaxAN, ID, AVO  FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID, AVO)` is a subquery, and it has the alias `t2`. The only thing you should adjust in the query is the table name (I've used `MyTable`), and the only thing in the table is the added autonumber field

Comment: I don't think access can deal with something like this, SELECT AN From (MyTable t1. T1 there represents nothing for the DB. I'll try to figure it out but I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Give me 15 minutes. I don't wanna take up more of your time for my knowledge shortages.

Comment: Access certainly can. You can run `SELECT t1.* FROM MyTable t1`, this assigns the alias `t1` to `MyTable`, and selects everything from it. It's pretty basic SQL. You can use `AS` if you want to explicitly assign the alias (`SELECT * FROM MyTable AS t1`), but that's just a redundant keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with your explanation. Sadly it looks like it will take 15-30 minutes to run so I'm gonna have to figure out some other way but the answer per se is correct.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add indexes. The solution I provided is pretty optimized when running with indexes on all joined fields (`AN`, `ID`, `AVO`, compound index `ID` + `AVO`), I doubt you will be able to go much faster

Comment: Do you mean composite index instead of compound index?

Comment: Yes, sorry, misspoke. English is not my native language